# How to implement chain lock in RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to implement lock in my application to let only one chain fragment execute at the time and any other to wait each other.

For example:

```
    val demoDao = DemoDao() // data that must be accessed only by one rx-chain fragment at one time

    Observable.range(0, 150)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapCompletable {
                dataLockManager.lock("action") { // fragment-start
                    demoDao.get()
                        .flatMapCompletable { data ->
                            demoDao.set(...)
                        }
                }                                // fragment-end
            }
            .subscribe()

    Observable.range(0, 100)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapCompletable {
                dataLockManager.lock("action") { // fragment-start
                    demoDao.get()
                            .flatMapCompletable { data ->
                                demoDao.set(...)
                            }
                }                                // fragment-end
            }
            .subscribe()
```

I tried to implement it via custom `Completable.create` with `CountDownLatch` but it may lead to deadlock.

And I suck at this point. What can you recommend me?

Answer (score 2):

To serialize access to `demoDao.get()`, there are a few ways of achieving this but try hard not to use a lock to do it as that can stuff up a reactive stream with deadlocks for starters (as you have found out).

If you do want to use a lock you should ensure that no lock is held across a stream signal like an emission to downstream or request to upstream. In that situation you can use a lock (shortlived).

One approach is to combine the actions of the two streams into one (with say `merge`) and  do the `demoDao` stuff on that one stream.

Another approach is to create a `PublisheSubject` using `PublishSubject.create().serialized()` which does the `demoDao.get()` stuff downstream and subscribe to it once only. Then the two sources you have mentioned can `.doOnNext(x -> subject.onNext())`. Depends if each source must know about failure independently or if it is acceptable that the `PublishSubject` subscription is the only spot where the failure is notified.

Answer (score 0):

in asynchronous world, using of locks is strongly discouraged. Instead, locking is modelled by serialized execution of an actor or a serial executor. In turn, actor can be modelled by an `Obserever` and serial executor by `Schedulers.single()`, though more experienced RxJava programmers can make more advice.